# How to check if disabled samaccountnames are contained/part of an enabled samaccountname in AD (e.g. the disabled user has -adm or -tst account?_

Tags: powershell

I am able to export the disabled users, but then from that .csv I want to check if they have active accounts in AD, containing their samaccount name + -adm or -tst. The script runs but the second export is blank.

```
$users = import-csv C:\Users\....csv
$OU = 'OU=Disabled users ...'

Get-ADUser -Property Enabled -filter * -SearchBase $OU | Where {$_.Enabled -like "False"}  | Select @{Name="samaccountname";Expression={$_.SamAccountName}} | Export-Csv  C:\Users\... -notypeinformation -encoding UTF8

$data = foreach($line in $users){
    
    

    $user = $line.samaccountname
    
    
    Get-ADUser -Filter {(samaccountname -like $user) -and (samaccountname -like "*-adm") -and (samaccountname -like "*-tst")} -Properties Enabled  | Where {$_.Enabled -like "True"} | select @{Name="SAPID";Expression={$_.samaccountname}}
        
        
}  $data | export-csv C:\Users\... -notypeinformation -encoding UTF8
```

Comment: take a look at `Ambiguous Name Resolution`. [*grin*]

Comment: You can also filter for enabled users in your `-Filter`; should also be comparing booleans to booleans: `$_.Enable -EQ $True/$False`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to find all those **Enabled Accounts ending in `-adm` OR `-tst` AND containing the SamAccountName of ANY disabled user found in `$OU`.**

If my assumption is correct, one way to approach the problem is to first query all the Disabled users in `$OU` and have them in memory (Note that there is no need to export them to CSV and then import them back again - *see inline comments*).

Once we have the list of Disabled users, we can loop over them to construct an [LDAP Filter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) which will be used to query all users at once, and lastly export to CSV if any user was found.

```sh
$users = Import-Csv C:\Users\....csv
$OU = 'OU=Disabled users ...'

# Hold disabled Users under `$OU` in memory, no reason to import the data from CSV
$disabledUsers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)" -SearchBase $OU |
    Select-Object SamAccountName
# Export Disabled Users
$disabledUsers | Export-Csv C:\Users\... -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8

# Construct an LDAP Filter to query al users at once
$filters = foreach($user in $disabledUsers) {
    '(samAccountName=*{0}*-adm)(samAccountName=*{0}*-tst)' -f $user.SamAccountName
}
$ldapFilter = "(&(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(|$(-join $filters)))"

# Query the users
$enabledUsers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter

# Check if any user could be found
if(-not $enabledUsers) {
    'No Enabled -adm or -tst Account Could be found...'
}
else {
    $enabledUsers | Select-Object @{ N = "SAPID"; E = { $_.SamAccountName} } | 
        Export-Csv C:\Users\... -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8
}
```

This is an example of how the filter would look like, having `user0` and `user1` as example `SamAccountName`:

```
(&
   (!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)
   (|
      (samAccountName=*user0*-adm)
      (samAccountName=*user0*-tst)
      (samAccountName=*user1*-adm)
      (samAccountName=*user1*-tst)
    )
)
```